# SFCC Customer Service Center custom actions

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I would like to know if somebody already customized the customer service center in SFCC project via custom actions.
I found only this page https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC3/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/customer_service_center/b2c_custom_actions.html

on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of CSC customization here https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/customer-service-center The Customer Service Center repository contains cartridges to illustrate how Customer Service Center can be customized.